# channel count differs on my site and 1ML

Tags: core-lightning

I wonder why:
lightning-cli getinfo;listfunds

```
{
  "id": "035aef5661e1a6e370db60dc0455796800afd5b51fbc12a0a8b34836b15f5d7ef6", 
  "alias": "TWronald✅", 
  "color": "15c315", 
  "num_peers": 41, 
  "num_pending_channels": 3, 
  "num_active_channels": 38, 
  "num_inactive_channels": 0, 
  "address": [
    {
      "type": "ipv4", 
      "address": "220.133.223.206", 
      "port": 9735
    }
  ], 
  "binding": [
    {
      "type": "ipv4", 
      "address": "0.0.0.0", 
      "port": 9735
    }
  ], 
  "version": "v0.6.3rc1-118-g0da4054", 
  "blockheight": 563691, 
  "network": "bitcoin", 
  "msatoshi_fees_collected": 82538
}

157278 satoshi available to fund channels
7318449 satoshi owned in channels
19485999 satoshi total channel capacity
---------------
Total funds: 7475727 satoshi
Percentage of total channel capacity owned: 37.5575
---------------
Add command line parameter [B] for BTC, [m] for mBTC, [y] for microBTC, [b] for bits and nothting or anything else for satoshi
by Rene Pickhardt.
Consider a tip: via curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"amount":ENTER_AN_INTEGER_AMOUNT_OF_SATOSHIS_INSTEAD_OF_THIS}' http://ln.rene-pickhardt.de/invoice
```

On 1ML.com:

```
Capacity
0.19280979 BTC (0.027%)
$751.22
Channel Count
37 (0.132%)
Connected Node Count
37 (1.120%)
```

Rene, I tried to send you some thanks, but it should be https and even then it didn't work.

Comment: 1ml says that the information about your mode was updated a month ago, no wonder it is different. The question is why does not 1ml reindexes your node more often. I would just ask them

Answer (score 1):

Since 1ml is not open source I can not give the exact reason. But some things are known that add to the discussion. The information about your node that you get from getinfo or listfunds are accurate and up to date.

New channels have to be announced over the gossip protocol so it will take some time until 1ml is aware of your most recent channels. This is one certain reason for the difference.

Another reason is that 1ml does not see your private channels since they are not announced over the gossip protocol. This could be the reason if the difference exists for a longer time.

Also it seems to me from my user experience from using 1ml that 1ml does not update its info in real time but does some batch processing (this part is speculation as their software is closed source) anyway this could also slow down the process of updating your node info.